# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'directory'

Tags: powershell

When I run this code in powershell I get an error that A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'directory'? Any idea what is wrong? Thank you

```
$Output = @()
$DirList = GCI \\server\share -directory | %{$_.FullName; GCI $_ -Directory|select -expandproperty FullName}
ForEach($Dir in $DirList){
    $ACLs=@()
    (get-acl $Dir).accesstostring.split("`n")|?{$_ -match "^(.+?admin(istrators|141))\s+?(\w+?)\s+?(.+)$"}|%{
        $ACLs+=[PSCUSTOMOBJECT]@{Group=$Matches[1];Type=$Matches[2];Access=$Matches[3]}
    }
    ForEach($ACL in $ACLs){
        if($Members){Remove-Variable Members}
        $Members = Get-ADGroupMember $ACL.Group -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|%{[string]$_.SamAccountName}
        $Output += "$Dir $($ACL.Group) $($ACL.Access) $($Members -join ",")"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in `$DirList = GCI \\server\share -directory` and `GCI $_ -Directory` The Get-ChildItem cmdlet does not support a `-directory` parameter (EDIT: before version 3).

It looks like you are trying to get and process every top level directory entry on a network file share. This can be achieved as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -path \\server\share |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
    ForEach-Object {

        Write-host $_.FullName

        # processing code here

    }
```

Comment: This is not true. The `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet does have a `-Directory` parameter, but it is not available prior to version 3.0.

Comment: Updated. Thanks Trevor.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to get the security group for each folder as well. And I only need the security group which ends in -W and its members

Answer (score 4):

You need PowerShell version 3.0 at a minimum to support the `-Directory` parameter on the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet. If you're on Windows 7, you can upgrade to Windows Management Framework Core 4.0 after installing the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1.